# Discord bot command options

Tags: python, discord, bots

I have problem with my bot

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, *, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)
```

When I type '/test some text', the console say

```
return await coro(ctx, *args, **kwargs)
```

> TypeError: test() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'arg'

Can somebody explain it ?

I want to create /test command with one option to choose in that case '/test *option to chosee* and type in option some text' then bot reply text that I put in option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you.

```
@bot.command()
async def say(interaction: discord.Interaction, word:str):
    await interaction.response.send_message(word)
```

You need to put the variable reference in the define function if it's str do `string:str` if it's int you can use `number:int`

Comment: I used /say test, and got similar error

    return await coro(ctx, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: say() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word'

Comment: maybe u can help me with create option on commands, like /say text: test text